# Isn't it better to use a single try catch instead of tons of TryParsing and other error handling sometimes?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, refactoring

I know people say it's bad to use exceptions for flow control and to only use exceptions for exceptional situations, but sometimes isn't it just cleaner and more elegant to wrap the entire block in a `try-catch`?

For example, let's say I have a dialog window with a `TextBox` where the user can type input in to be parsed in a key-value sort of manner.

This situation is not as contrived as you might think because I've inherited code that has to handle this exact situation (albeit not with farm animals).

Consider this wall of code:

```
class Animals
{
    public int catA, catB;
    public float dogA, dogB;
    public int mouseA, mouseB, mouseC;
    public double cow;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "Sets all the farm animals CAT 3 5 DOG 21.3 5.23 MOUSE 1 0 1 COW 12.25";

        string[] splitInput = input.Split(' ');

        string[] animals = { "CAT", "DOG", "MOUSE", "COW", "CHICKEN", "GOOSE", "HEN", "BUNNY" };

        Animals animal = new Animals();

        for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.Length; i++)
        {
            string token = splitInput[i];

            if (animals.Contains(token))
            {
                switch (token)
                {
                    case "CAT":
                        animal.catA = int.Parse(splitInput[i + 1]);
                        animal.catB = int.Parse(splitInput[i + 2]);
                        break;
                    case "DOG":
                        animal.dogA = float.Parse(splitInput[i + 1]);
                        animal.dogB = float.Parse(splitInput[i + 2]);
                        break;
                    case "MOUSE":
                        animal.mouseA = int.Parse(splitInput[i + 1]);
                        animal.mouseB = int.Parse(splitInput[i + 2]);
                        animal.mouseC = int.Parse(splitInput[i + 3]);
                        break;
                    case "COW":
                        animal.cow = double.Parse(splitInput[i + 1]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In actuality there are a lot more farm animals and more handling than that. A lot of things can go wrong though. The user could enter in the wrong number of parameters. The user can enter the input in an incorrect format. The user could specify numbers too large or too small for the data type to handle.

All these different errors could be handled without exceptions through the use of `TryParse`, checking how many parameters the user tried to use for a specific animal, checking if the parameter is too large or too small for the data type (because TryParse just returns 0), but every one should result in the same thing:

A `MessageBox` appearing telling the user that the inputted data is invalid and to fix it. My boss doesn't want different message boxes for different errors. So instead of doing all that, why not just wrap the block in a `try-catch` and in the catch statement just display that error message box and let the user try again?

Maybe this isn't the best example but think of any other scenario where there would otherwise be tons of error handling that could be substituted for a single try-catch. Is that not the better solution?

Comment: IMO a user can be expected to type in wrong input data, wrong input data is then part of the normal program flow which would make me inclined to stay away from exceptions. In addition throwing exceptions for non-faults makes debugging harder as a good approach IMO is run with break on all exceptions (especially useful when using WinDBG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Try-Catch-Finalize is different then using TryParse. TryParse doesn't stop code from executing and instead of throwing exceptions, it simply skips error and leaves variable uninitialized.

Writing safe codes is a lot more then error handling and "many can go wrong", that is when limiting comes in handy. We limit user's freedom for sake of proper execution and good result's, next step is error handling.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much control you need of the error messages. Using a "catch-all" approach, all you will be a able to inform to the user is that "Something went wrong, try again".

Using one big try-catch block and catching `Exception` you will be hiding other errors in your code, not entirely related to int parsing. You should at least try to narrow down the type of expected exceptions.

Also take into account that `TryParse` will let you continue with the rest of the parsing, meaning you could track down and record all the problems and later inform them in a detailed manner to the user. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I threw together a quick parser combinator-like example for your case. When it comes to parsing semi-complex syntax parser combinators are quite powerful. In addition a parser combinator library can be extended to support human readable errors why a parser failed.

Perhaps it can you give you ideas on different ways to deal with the task.

With some parser primitives parsing a "cat" would look something like this:

```
static IParseResult<Cat> ParseCat(this ParserState ps)
{
    var value = new Cat();
    var result = 
            ps.AttemptTo (() => ps.ParseToken("CAT"))
        &&  ps.AttemptTo (ps.ParseDouble, out value.A)
        &&  ps.AttemptTo (ps.ParseDouble, out value.B)
        ;

    return ps.Result(result, value);
}
```

Similar for dog, cow and mouse. Parsing an animal is a combination of all these:

```
    static IParseResult<Animal> ParseAnimal(this ParserState ps)
    {
        Animal value = null;
        var result =
                ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseCat    , out value)
            ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDog    , out value)
            ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseMouse  , out value)
            ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseCow    , out value)
            ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseUnknown, out value)
            ;

        return ps.Result(result, value);
    }
```

Finally we like to parse the input as many animals:

```
    public static IParseResult<Animal[]> ParseAnimals(this ParserState ps)
    {
        Animal[] value;
        var result = ps.AttemptMany(ps.ParseAnimal, out value);
        return ps.Result(result, value);
    }
```

The full sample:

```
namespace ParseTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Linq;

    static class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            var input = "Sets all the farm animals CAT 3 5 DOG 21.3 5.23 MOUSE 1 0 1 COW 12.25";

            Console.WriteLine(input);

            var ps = new ParserState(input.Split(' '));

            var result = ps.ParseAnimals();

            if (result.Success)
            {
                foreach (var animal in result.Value.Where(v => !(v is Unknown)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(animal);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parse failure");
            }

        }
    }


    // ParserState tracks where we are in the input
    class ParserState
    {
        public readonly string[] Tokens;
        public int CurrentPosition;

        public ParserState(string[] tokens) 
        {
            Tokens = tokens ?? new string[0];
        }


        public string Peek
        {
            get
            {
                if (CurrentPosition < 0)
                {
                    return "";
                }

                if (CurrentPosition >= Tokens.Length)
                {
                    return "";
                }

                return Tokens[CurrentPosition];
            }
        }

        public string PeekAndAdvance ()
        {
            var result = Peek;

            ++CurrentPosition;

            return result;
        }

        public bool EndOfStream
        {
            get { return CurrentPosition >= Tokens.Length; }
        }

    }
    struct Empty
    {

    }

    // ParseResult are the result of parsers, it might be a succcess or failure
    interface IParseResult<out T>
    {
        ParserState State { get; }
        bool Success { get; }
        T Value { get; }
    }

    class ParseResult<T> : IParseResult<T>
    {
        readonly ParserState m_state;
        readonly bool m_success;
        readonly T m_value;

        public ParseResult(ParserState state, bool success, T value)
        {
            m_state = state;
            m_success = success;
            m_value = value;
        }

        public ParserState State
        {
            get { return m_state; }
        }

        public bool Success
        {
            get { return m_success; }
        }

        public T Value 
        {
            get { return m_value; }
        }
    }

    static class ParserExtensions
    {
        public static IParseResult<T> Result<T>(this ParserState ps, bool success, T value)
        {
            return new ParseResult<T>(ps, success, value);
        }

        public static IParseResult<T> Success<T>(this ParserState ps, T value)
        {
            return ps.Result(true, value);
        }

        public static IParseResult<T> Failure<T>(this ParserState ps)
        {
            return ps.Result(true, default(T));
        }

        public static bool AttemptTo<T>(this ParserState ps, Func<IParseResult<T>> action)
        {
            T value;
            return ps.AttemptTo(action, out value);
        }

        // Attempts to run a parser, 
        // if the parser fails the parser state is returned to its previous state
        public static bool AttemptTo<T>(this ParserState ps, Func<IParseResult<T>> action, out T value)
        {
            value = default(T);
            if (ps.EndOfStream)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var currentPos = ps.CurrentPosition;

            var result = action();

            if (result.Success)
            {
                value = result.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                ps.CurrentPosition = currentPos;
            }

            return result.Success;
        }

        // Attempts to run a parser many times and build an array of values, 
        // if the parser fails the parser state is returned to its previous state
        // and the result is returned
        public static bool AttemptMany<T>(this ParserState ps, Func<IParseResult<T>> action, out T[] values)
        {
            values = new T[0];
            if (ps.EndOfStream)
            {
                return true;
            }

            var parsedValues = new List<T>();

            var currentPos = ps.CurrentPosition;

            IParseResult<T> result;

            while ((result = action ()).Success)
            {
                currentPos = ps.CurrentPosition;
                parsedValues.Add(result.Value);
            }

            ps.CurrentPosition = currentPos;

            values = parsedValues.ToArray();

            return true;
        }

        static IParseResult<Empty> ParseToken(this ParserState ps, string token)
        {
            var value = new Empty();
            var result = ps.PeekAndAdvance().Equals(token, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }

        static IParseResult<double> ParseDouble(this ParserState ps)
        {
            double value;
            var result = double.TryParse(ps.PeekAndAdvance(), out value);
            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }

        static IParseResult<Cat> ParseCat(this ParserState ps)
        {
            var value = new Cat();
            var result = 
                    ps.AttemptTo (() => ps.ParseToken("CAT"))
                &&  ps.AttemptTo (ps.ParseDouble, out value.A)
                &&  ps.AttemptTo (ps.ParseDouble, out value.B)
                ;

            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }

        static IParseResult<Dog> ParseDog(this ParserState ps)
        {
            var value = new Dog();
            var result =
                    ps.AttemptTo(() => ps.ParseToken("DOG"))
                &&  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDouble, out value.A)
                &&  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDouble, out value.B)
                ;

            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }

        static IParseResult<Mouse> ParseMouse(this ParserState ps)
        {
            var value = new Mouse();
            var result =
                    ps.AttemptTo(() => ps.ParseToken("MOUSE"))
                &&  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDouble, out value.A)
                &&  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDouble, out value.B)
                &&  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDouble, out value.C)
                ;

            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }

        static IParseResult<Cow> ParseCow(this ParserState ps)
        {
            var value = new Cow();
            var result =
                    ps.AttemptTo(() => ps.ParseToken("COW"))
                &&  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDouble, out value.A)
                ;

            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }

        static IParseResult<Unknown> ParseUnknown(this ParserState ps)
        {
            ps.PeekAndAdvance();
            return ps.Success(new Unknown());
        }

        static IParseResult<Animal> ParseAnimal(this ParserState ps)
        {
            Animal value = null;
            var result =
                    ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseCat    , out value)
                ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseDog    , out value)
                ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseMouse  , out value)
                ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseCow    , out value)
                ||  ps.AttemptTo(ps.ParseUnknown, out value)
                ;

            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }

        public static IParseResult<Animal[]> ParseAnimals(this ParserState ps)
        {
            Animal[] value;
            var result = ps.AttemptMany(ps.ParseAnimal, out value);
            return ps.Result(result, value);
        }
    }

    class Animal
    {

    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public double A;
        public double B;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return new {Type = "CAT", A, B}.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public double A;
        public double B;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return new { Type = "DOG", A, B }.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Mouse : Animal
    {
        public double A;
        public double B;
        public double C;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return new { Type = "MOUSE", A, B, C }.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Cow : Animal
    {
        public double A;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return new { Type = "COW", A}.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Unknown : Animal
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return new { Type = "UNKNOWN"}.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

PS. FParsec is last I checked the best parser combinator library for .NET: http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html

PS. MicroParser is a C# variant of FParsec but aimed at being smaller while sacrificing the ability to parse of giant strings: http://microparser.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just FYI: Parser combinators can with ease handle syntaxes like these: 1+2*x + 3*(1+Z).